# mysql return data based on expected stock

Tags: mysql

I have a table Fruit, with 2 columns Date and quantity. It indicates the date the fruits were added to stock.

Products are sold based on the First in First out principle.

If I want to sell 40 apples based on the FIFO principle , for  below scenario, what sql query do I write? I am expecting record 1,2,3 to be returned

```
+-id-+----date----+---quantity--+
 1   | 02/05/2015 |    10
 2   | 03/05/2015 |    20
 3   | 04/05/2015 |    30
 4   | 05/05/2015 |    30

select * from fruit where quantity less than < 40 order by date asc
//returns record 1 and 2 only.
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: mysql workbench 6.3

Comment: I mean MySQL **server** version!

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of date field? 
If it is varchar then you have to use mysql date function and then perform the query and other solution is that FIFO principle can be implemented with the id also like this

```
select * from fruit where quantity < 40 order by id asc
```

Comment: thanks for helping. no such thing as 'less than < ' in mysql

Answer (score 0):

- We first calculate the rolling sum using [Session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).
- Then, use the result-set in a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and find the dates where total sum crosses the "barrier" of 40. Barrier is reached when the New rolling Sum is greater than or equal to 40. We set the barrier value to 1 at this point, 0 for rows before it, and 2 and more, for the rows afterwards.
- `date` is a Keyword in MySQL. You should really avoid using it as a table name; else use backticks around it

Try (works for all MySQL versions):

```
SELECT dt.id, 
       dt.`date`, 
       dt.quantity
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    f.id, 
    f.`date`, 
    f.quantity, 
    @barrier := CASE
                  WHEN 
                       (@tot_qty := @tot_qty + f.quantity) >= 40
                  THEN (@barrier + 1)
                  ELSE 0
                END AS barrier 
  FROM 
    Fruit AS f 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @tot_qty := 0, 
                     @barrier := 0) AS user_init
  ORDER BY f.`date`
) AS dt 
WHERE dt.barrier <= 1
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gCWctyH4fJjrTKj4ecXyXN/2)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. The db fiddle demo return record 1 and 2. I want record 3 returned also so that i can extract the 10 from it to get the 40 I want

Comment: @RahlSK any updates ? did u check the latest query ?